# jQuery popup bubble, element moves in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, bubble-popup

I'm creating a popup for elements in the DOM, much like Qtip. I know there are alot of done plugins for this but I wanted to create one myself.

Basicly what the code does:

Hover element, take that elements offset and alter a little bit so that the popup is over the element.

Show the popup element and then change its position according to the element that was hovered.

But it seems like I've failed. It doesn't work in IE7. 
When I hover an element in IE7 my popup shows in the right location BUT the element that was hovered changes position.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/egj46/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say what exactly is causing that, it can be solved by moving the popup div "pHolder" to after the content.

Comment: Thank you! Strange problem, would be sweet to know what caused it. Thanks once again!